# How to create custom alert in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

I want to create a custom alert in Google Analytics according to [this guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033021?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)
But this functionality is available only for Universal Analytics properties. And I can't find the custom alerts section for my GA4 properties as well as for Firebase Analytics property. There is a similar thing - Custom Insights but looks like it's not possible to select your own events there as trigger. And I need these alerts for data coming from mobile apps (they are using Firebase Analytics). Is there any workaround, is it possible to create a custom alert for GA4?

Why do I need a custom alert in the first place? I want to have a notification when multiple users are not finishing the sign-up process.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, there are no ways to do it in interface. You can eventually build a your customized system that reads data in BigQuery every day and sends you an email based on the rules you have defined.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Still relevant?